# PostGIS change from multipoint to point and add column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to change the geometry of a PostGIS db from multipoint to point and using this expressions works quite well

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom AS the_POINT_geom
  FROM MULTIPOINT_table;
```

But when trying to add this as new column via

```
ALTER TABLE  your_table ADD COLUMN the_POINT_geom double precision;

UPDATE your_table SET the_POINT_geom = (ST_Dump(geom)).geom;
```

this only causes an error:

> set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE

Is there a way to add the point geometry as new column?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE or set-returning functions are not allowed in UPDATE [not exactly sure b/c error is given in german]

Comment: if you had an RECORD_ID you could use to re-join the data, you could build a new table of just the_point_geom and the record_id, then use that table to do the update instead of the aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `UPDATE` is a per-row operation and cannot expand the table. `ST_Dump` returns a `SETOF RECORD` which cannot be mapped to a single row *directly* (you can expand a `SET` within a subquery or CTE and return/join a single row from there), even if your *MultiPoint* actually consists of only one point geometry!

If that is indeed the case, you can extract that point and `UPDATE` the column:

```
UPDATE your_table
  SET the_POINT_geom = ST_GeometryN(geom, 1)
;
```

or, to keep only the initial column:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE GEOMETRY(POINT, <SRID>)
    USING ST_SetSRID(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1), <SRID>)
;
```

---

If your *MultiPoint* consists of more than one point geometry, and you want to expand all of them into a table, you will need to create a new one using e.g. your `SELECT` query.

Comment: Alright, got it. I now solved it by creating a new table and joining the data via id number, but probably your solution will do the job more elegant as my multipoint object indeed consists of only one point each

Comment: @JWW It will...,) Try it, and consider accepting, so that others get the idea, too.